# Linear transformation of continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Define $T: C(\mathbb{R}^{N})\to C(\mathbb{B}^{N})$ (where $ \mathbb{B}^{N}$ is the open unit ball $\mathbb{R}^{N}) $ by the formula

$$(Tf)(x')=(1-|x'|)f\left(\frac{x'}{1-|x'|}\right)$$

for $x'\in \mathbb{B}^{N}.$ Then $T$ is linear.

Now, consider subspace

$$X:=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}^{N}): \ Tf \text{ extends to a bounded continuous function on } \overline{\mathbb{B}^N}\}.$$
Equipped with the norm
$$ \lVert f\rVert:=\sup\left\{|(Tf)(x)|: \ x\in\overline{\mathbb{B}^N} \right\}$$
$X$ becomes Banach space and if $f\in X$, then in particular $f$ has a linear growth, i.e.
$$|f(x)|\leq C(1+|x|),$$
where $ C\geq 0$ is some constant.

What I'm trying to do now is to find a **linear** transformation $$S:C(\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R})\to C(\mathbb{B}^N\times\mathbb{B}^1),$$ such that elements of a function space
$$ Y:=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}^N\times\mathbb{R}): \ Sf \text{ extends to a bounded continuous function on } \overline{\mathbb{B}^N\times \mathbb{B}^1}\}.$$
satisfy a growth condition of the form
$$|f(x,y)|\leq C(1+|x|+|y|^2)$$
for some constant $C\geq 0$. Norm in $Y$ is defined analogously to the norm in $$.

After numerous failed trials I decided to show this problem to this community. Thanks in advance for any suggestions how to tackle this problem.

Comment: a constant function is alway continuous ... and surely "linear"

Comment: @user251257: and how is that relevant to my problem?

Comment: Your question has a trivial answer, that you likely don't want.

Comment: @user251257: you are right, I corrected my question. Thanks!

Comment: So ... $T$ is not defined on $C(\mathbb R^N)$ is it?

Comment: @zhw: $T$ maps a function from $C(\mathbb{R}^N)$ to a function in $C(\mathbb{B}^N)$. Then $Tf:\mathbb{B}^N\to\mathbb{R}$ and in the first part I require that $Tf$ extends continuously to $\overline{\mathbb{B}^N}$

Comment: No, you are restricting to a subspace with a growth condition, aren't you?

Comment: @zhw: the growth condition at infinity is a consequence of that we can extend $Tf$

Comment: Come on now. Not every function in the full space satisfies the growth condition, right? Therefore T is not defined on the full space $C(\mathbb R^N)$ right?

Comment: @zhw: Well, I'm interested in a function space $$X:=\{f\in C(\mathbb{R}^N): \ Tf \text{ extends to a continuous bounded function on } \overline{B^N} \}$$. Then this space is a normed space with the norm given by $$\lVert f\rVert:=\sup\left\{ |(Tf)(x)|:\ x\in\overline{\mathbb{B^N}} \right\},$$ which can be equivalently expressed as $$\lVert f\rVert=\sup\left\{ \frac{|f(x)|}{1+|x|}: x\in\mathbb{R}^N\right\}.$$ From there you easily deduce growth condition.

Comment: You need to restate the problem. It is unclear at the moment. You want to define $T$ on the full space by the formula you have, right? And and then you want to look at a special subset of the full space, $X$, etc. It's confusing the way it's written now.

Comment: @zhw: I corrected my initial post. Hope it is clearer now. Thanks for your remarks!

Comment: In analogy to your $T$, it would be natural to take homeomorphisms $\alpha \colon \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{B}^N$ and $\beta \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{B}^1$, and try something of the form $(Sf)(x',y') = \mu(x',y')\cdot f(\alpha^{-1}(x'),\beta^{-1}(y'))$. Well, then $(S^{-1}g)(x,y) = \frac{1}{\mu(\alpha(x),\beta(y))}g(\alpha(x),\beta(y))$. If $g$ extends continuously to $\mathbb{B}^N\times \mathbb{B}^1$, then in particular $g$ is bounded. So if you have $\frac{1}{\mu(\alpha(x),\beta(y))} = 1 + \lvert x\rvert + \lvert y\rvert^2$, you have your growth condition.